# I am creating a simple lambda function Do I use IHttpClientFactory to create HttpClient or use new HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I am creating a simple lambda function
which uses HttpClient.

Do I use IHttpClientFactory to create HttpClient or use new HttpClient

because event time the function get called IHttpClientFactory getting created and distroyed at the end. so will it really reuse HttpClient

Comment: This document may help:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#httpclient-and-lifetime-management

Comment: this didn't say about using IHttpClientFactory in the azure function.